# Dealing Cards in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm making a program that deals cards and assigns 5 random cards to each player, and it works up until I try to print the hands of each player (showHand function). I am trying to print the cards the given player has but it's telling me "cards" isn't a global attribute. I know it isn't, but I don't know how to print the cards for the player otherwise. Help?

```
import random

NUMCARDS = 52
DECK = 0
PLAYER = 1
COMP = 2

cardLoc = [0] * NUMCARDS
suitName = ("hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs")
rankName = ("Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven",
            "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King")
playerName = ("deck", "player", "computer")


#assigns random card to given player
def assignCard(str):

    #generates random card number to assign to player
    randomNum = random.randrange(0, NUMCARDS-1)

    #makes sure card being picked for player is not already assigned to another player
    while cardLoc[randomNum] != 0:
        randomNum = random.randrange(0, NUMCARDS-1)

    cardLoc[randomNum] = str


#shows all the cards in the deck
def showDeck():
    print "#      Card       Location"
    print "---------------------------"

    cardNum = 0

    for x in rankName:
        #assigns all ranks
        rank = x

        for y in suitName:
            #assigns all suits
            suit = y

            cards = "%s of %s" % (rank, suit)
            cardNum += 1

            location = cardLoc[cardNum-1]
            location = detLocation(location)

            print "%s  %s %s" % (cardNum, cards, location)
            global cards


#has program print out appropriate location instead of number
def detLocation(location):
    if location == PLAYER:
        return "Player"
    elif location == COMP:
        return "Computer"
    else:
        return "Deck"


#shows given player's hand... but not their foot (;
def showHand(str):
    global cards
    location = detLocation(str)
    print "Displaying %s Hand:" %location

    for i in range(5):
        cardLoc[cards] = str
        print "%s" % cardNum


#calls all functions necessary
def main():
    clearDeck()

    for i in range(5):
        assignCard(PLAYER)
        assignCard(COMP)

    #showDeck()
    showHand(PLAYER)
    showHand(COMP)
```

Comment: What variable stores the cards for a player?

Comment: @Cody-Guru Cards does, but it's defined in the showDeck function.

Comment: I suggest that you back away from the code and describe in English what you are trying to do. When the program starts what is the first thing it should do? The second? Next? Then what? Keep going until the program ends. Writing this out will help you better understand the steps to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: @Code-Guru That's not my problem though. I know exactly what I need the showHand function to do, I just don't know how to print the cards the given player (str) has.

Comment: So where *are* the cards that the player has? That *is* your problem. IMO, backing up a little will help you understand what you are currently doing and possibly help you find a way to solve the problem on your own.

Comment: @Cody-Guru Like I said, in the showDeck function...

Comment: @Code-Guru I've tried that multiple times. I've been working on this code for about 3 days straight.

Comment: `cards` in `showDeck` contains *all* the cards from the deck, not just the ones dealt to a player. How do you store the *five* cards that are dealt to the player?

Comment: On a totally unrelated note, I strongly suggest changing all of your references to `str` to something else.  `str` is Python's string object, and it's not really a good idea to use that name for other stuff.  It's recommended to name your function arguments to reflect what's actually coming in.  For example, `assignCard` is being passed an integer, not a string, and that integer is the player's number, so a better name for that incoming argument may be `player`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your `assignCard` function doesn't modify the global variable (I assume that is what you actually wont to do)
so you have to add a line there like `global cardLoc`
having modified this global variable you can print your cards with the following code

```
for i in range(NUMCARDS-1):
    if cardLoc[i] == str:
```

print whatever card is assigned to the position of `i` in your deck.

Comment: I know this is probably a stupid question but what do you mean by "print whatever card is assgned to the position of iin your deck"? The rest of the code works well though!

Comment: Well I assume that your deck is generated somehow having for exemple first element Ace of hearts, then Two of hearts and so on ending with a king of clubs as `deck[NUMCARDS-1]`

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a global cards object that gets initialized and contains the label. Similar to what you do in `showDeck`. It could be just an array of `NUMCARDS`. Then in `showHand` you iterate through cardLoc and print only the ones given to the user:

```
for i in NUMCARDS:
    if cardLoc[i] == str:
        print cards[i]
```

I'm just not sure your object hierarchy is the most proper one for this case, but I'm just trying to solve your issue without heavily modifying your code.

Answer (score 2):

This might not help with your specific problem, but perhaps it will give you some ideas as you go forward with Python.

```
import random

def main():
    suits = 'S H D C'.split()
    ranks = '2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 X J Q K A'.split()
    deck  = [r + s for s in suits for r in ranks]
    n_players = 4
    hand_size = 5

    random.shuffle(deck)
    hands = deal(deck, n_players, hand_size)

    for h in hands:
        print h

def deal(deck, n_players, hand_size):
    # A general-purpose dealing function.
    # It takes a deck and returns a list of hands.
    # Each hand is a list of cards dealt from the top of the deck.
    hands = [[] for _ in range(n_players)]
    i = -1
    for _ in range(hand_size):
        for h in hands:
            i += 1
            h.append(deck[i])
    return hands

main()
```

A few general points about the example:

- Rather than selecting random items from a list (and then worrying about whether subsequent selections are duplicates of prior selections) this example simply shuffles the deck and then deals from the top.
- The dealing function does not rely on any global variables. Instead it receives the deck and other parameters as arguments and then returns the desired hands. To the extent that you can organize your programs to minimize (and localize) reliance on global variables you are usually better off (for many reasons).
- The example uses list comprehension, which is a handy technique for creating lists in Python (where `deck` and `hands` are initialized).

Comment: +1 but `deal` can be written using a list comprehension: `def deal(deck, n, hs): return [deck[i * hs:(i + 1) * hs] for i in xrange(n)]`

Answer (score 2):

A number of problems, so I suggest the real fix would be to throw this away and start over.

First thing to do: strings are for people, not computers, so don't represent cards as strings until you have to print something. Everywhere else, they should be numbers. Either a single number for each card, or a "card" object with numbers for rank and suit. Both player hands and decks are then just simple arrays (or in Python, lists).

Create a single global "deck" list from which to deal all the cards, initialize it with one of each, then deal to the player hands. There are two ways to deal random cards from a deck--your method is neither of them. Either (1) "shuffle" the deck using an algorithm called Fisher-Yates (Python's `random.shuffle()` does this) and pop cards off the end of the deck array as you append them to hand arrays, or (2) To deal each card, select a card randomly from the *remaining cards* deck, append it to the hand, and *remove* it from the deck. This is also easy in Python with `random.choose()` and `remove()`.

A minor pythonism: don't use "str" as a variable name, it's already a built-in type.